# Python - How to reuse a method from an abstract class by calling with a custom parameter from a subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have an abstract class with a `parse_metrics_meta` method that I want to be used with a different parameter by its subclass. Currently I've implemented it by just overriding the method.

Is there a more proper and generic way to do this in Python? For example by calling the method from `CustomMetricParser` with a `custom_meta_key` parameter?

```
class MetricParser(ABC):
    def __init__(self, app_context: AppContext):
        self.app_context = app_context

def parse_metrics_meta(self, df):
    return parse_meta(
        df,
        self.app_context.get("meta_key_1"),
        self.app_context.get("meta_key_2"))
```

//

```
class CustomMetricParser(MetricParser):
    def __init__(self, custom_meta_key: str):
        self.custom_meta_key = custom_meta_key

def parse_metrics_meta(self, df):
    return parse_meta(
        df,
        self.app_context.get("meta_key_1"),
        self.app_context.get(self.custom_meta_key))
```

Comment: This looks fine. Just remember to call `super().__init__()` in your new `__init__()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Fast scratch:

```
class CRawMetricsMeta:
  def __init__(self, fields):
    self._fields = fields # list of fields names

  def parse(self, df):
    return parse_meta(df, *self._fields) # here was typo :)
  
class MetricParser(ABC):
  def __init__(self, app_context: AppContext):
    self._metrics = CRawMetricsMeta([
      app_context.get("meta_key_1"),
      app_context.get("meta_key_2")
    ])

  def parse_metrics_meta(self, df):
    return self._metrics.parse(df)

class CustomMetricParser(ABC):
  def __init__(self, app_context: AppContext, custom_meta_key: str):
    self._metrics = CRawMetricsMeta([
      app_context.get("meta_key_1"),
      custom_meta_key
    ])

  def parse_metrics_meta(self, df):
    return self._metrics.parse(df)
```

---

I didn't exactly understand your task, but I'm assuming that `df` is a kinda table/DataFrame with named columns. If it's so, then the most logical step would be introducing `IShema` (too bad, that Python didn't have interfaces). Here are *one* of many opportunities:

```
class IDataSchema:
  def columns(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

class CdsList(IDataSchema):
  def __init__(self, fields):
    self._fields = fields # list of fields names

  def columns(self):
    return self._fields.copy()
  
# here is light magic
class CdsReplaced(IDataSchema):
  def __init__(self, schema, newColumns):
    self._schema = schema # underlying IDataSchema
    self._newColumns = newColumns

  def columns(self):
    res = self._schema.columns()
    # replace columns
    for index, name in self._newColumns:
      res[index] = name
    return res  

# here is dark magic
class CdsFromContext(IDataSchema):
  def __init__(self, schema, app_context: AppContext):
    self._schema = schema # underlying IDataSchema
    self._context = app_context

  def columns(self):
    res = self._schema.columns()
    # read settings and update res
    return res

# shorthand
class CdsDefault(CdsList):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(['A', 'B', 'C'])

##########################
class CParser:
  def __init__(self, schema):
    self._schema = schema # underlying IDataSchema

  def parse(self, df):
    columns = self._schema.columns()
    return parse_meta(df, columns)
##########################
class MetricParser(ABC):
  def __init__(self, schema: IDataSchema):
    self._metrics = CParser( schema )

  def parse_metrics_meta(self, df):
    return self._metrics.parse(df)

class CustomMetricParser(ABC):
  def __init__(self, schema: IDataSchema, custom_meta_key: str):
    self._metrics = CParser(
      CdsReplaced(
        schema=schema,
        newColumns=[(2, custom_meta_key)] # 2 as example
      )
    )
    
  def parse_metrics_meta(self, df):
    return self._metrics.parse(df)

##########################
# usage
schema = CdsFromContext(schema=CdsDefault(), app_context=app_context)

simple = MetricParser(schema)
custom = CustomMetricParser(schema, 'custom')
```

Many things depends on your tasks. I don't know what is better for you, unfortunally.

Comment: Please, ask here if something wrong/unclear  and I will improve my answer.

Comment: Am I correct that `fields` in `CRawMetricsMeta` should be a `dict`? Also, I want to be able to construct arguments passed to `parse_meta()` to have multiple default values and one argument that could be overridden by the subclasses of `MetricParser`. So that the subclasses pass only one argument that they overide and the default parameters are defined only in `MetricParser`. The number and order of arguments passes to `parse_meta()` matter

Comment: @samba I updated my answer. (maybe you received the notification, I'm not sure)